# How many ways are there to distribute pens between two girls and one guy?

Tags: combinatorics

There are two girls and one guy and 121 pens. How many ways are there to distribute pens between two girls and one guy, so that the girls have the same number of pens. The pens all are identical.
Please can you explain a bit more deeply?

Comment: Have you tried yourself?

Comment: It makes a big difference if the pens are considered all identical, or all distinct. I suspect identical is intended.

Comment: The pens all are the identical.

Comment: Are the girls considered identical as well, or should we distinguish them when counting ways?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Choose an even number $n\in[0,\dots,121]$.

Give $n/2$ pens to each girl, and $121-n$ pens to the boy.

There are $61$ even numbers between $0$ and $121$, hence $61$ ways to distribute the pens.

Comment: Am i right that in the case, when pens is differ, in this case we need to compute arrangement A  = 121 ! / (121-61) !   ?

Comment: @ՎարդանԳրիգորյան: If then pens are different then you need to calculate $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{60}\binom{120}{n}\cdot\binom{60}{n}$.

Answer (score -1):

mathematical modelling of this situation is $2x + 2y = 120$ where
$x$ is the number of pens for a girl, and $2y + 1$ is the number
of pen for the boy. therefore $x + y = 60$ with $y$ ranging from
$0$ to $59$, then  the number of way to do this task is $60$

Comment: barak manos: be nice and give something to the girl.

Comment: Why would $y$ range from $0$ to $59$ and not  from $0$ to $60$?

Comment: we should give something to the girl

Comment: Where exactly is that stated within the question?

Comment: to distribute pens between two girls and one guy

Comment: Well, that's not quite the same as "we should give something to the girls".

Comment: in any case, thank you, can be a matter of language and culture and not a mathétmatiques problem, we understand well and thank you again for your comments.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think that there's any language-based interpretation here. The question is stated very clearly as distributing the pens between the girls and the boy, without any restriction on the minimum number of pens per girl.